# Can't run rails command when installing Rails without RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I can't get to install rails correctly, after doing "sudo gem install rails", all goes well, but if I try doing "rails -v", I get "Rails is not currently installed on this system...", I'm not using RVM, I installied Ruby through Homebrew.

The rails executable is in "/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p286/bin/rails", but even if I add that path to my $PATH it won't find it, or something else in RubyGems is going wrong...

Comment: If I do "which rails", I get /usr/bin/rails.

Comment: It seems that I have 2 rails executables, one in "/usr/bin/", and another in "/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p286/bin", I copied the one from the second folder to the first one, and it works now. Wish I knew how to make gem install rails in "/usr/bin/" from now on...

Comment: Check your gem installation path (`echo $GEM_HOME`). This should be something ending in `gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286` and is where rails and other gem should be getting installed.

Answer (score 0):

With homebrew, just use `gem install rails` or any gem name. Dont use `sudo`. That works for me.

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/rails
```